# TypoScript DB Query in split function

Tags: string, split, typo3, typoscript

first of all i would like to mention that I'm pretty new to TypoScript. 
I've created a form in the backend of Typo3 where one of its fields creates a comma seperated list with the uid of connected pages (input type group).

My frontend should now loop over my variable and output specific data of those connected pages. Currently my code (see below) loops over my list and outputs them wrapped in a paragraph tag. Is it possible to extend the wrap field to create a more complex output. I'ld like to get some info of these pages from the database (e.g. DB:pages:|:title)?

```
lib.testObject= COA
lib.testObject{

    30 = TEXT
    30.field = combination
    30.split {
        token = ,
        cObjNum = 1
        1.current = 1
        1.wrap = <p>|</p>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
lib.testObject = TEXT
lib.testObject {
    wrap = <ul>|</ul>
    field = combination
    split {
        token = ,
        cObjNum = 1
        1.cObject = RECORDS
        1.cObject {
            source.current = 1
            tables = pages
            dontCheckPid = 1
            conf.pages = TEXT
            conf.pages.field = title
            conf.pages.wrap = <li>|</li>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: didn't work for me. at least the output is an empty ul. any further ideas?

Comment: sorry, it should be field = combination instead of value = combination.